# Паттерн для замены части буквенных символов в словах другими символами в Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, символы, замена, проект

Задался вопросом, как, используя паттерн (пробовал что-то типа такого:  `<pattern>imya=[^\"]{3}([^\"]+)</pattern>`, но, увы) для проекта на java, заменять часть буквенных символов в словах другими символами в соответствии с условиями:

1. Если в имени больше семи знаков, то нужно удалить все знаки, кроме первого и двух последних, а заместо удаленных знаков вставить три знака "`***`".
   К примеру: `Екатерина => Е***на`.
2. Если в имени равно семь или меньше знаков, то нужно удалить все знаки кроме первого, а заместо удаленных знаков вставить знак "`*`" по количеству убранных символов. К примеру: `Сергей => С*****` или `Ян => Я*`.
3. Если в имени есть знаки тире или пробел, то удалить все символы, кроме первого символа, разделяющего символа (тире или пробела) и символа, следующего за разделяющим символом. Заместо удаленных знаков вставить три знака "`***`". К примеру: `Жан-Поль => Ж***-П***`.

Очень нужна помощь. Благодарю!

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Фактически задача сводится к тому, чтобы найти некий общий шаблон для имени как последовательности букв, включающей дефис `"-"`, а затем каждое имя "маскировать" в зависимости от указанных условий.  Важно отметить, что для определения букв используется класс символов `\p{L}` (`p{Letter}`) из категории Юникода.

Таким образом, сначала применяется [`Matcher::replaceAll`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java9/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-), в котором для каждого совпадения `MatchResult` будет вызываться функция замены:

```java
// class MyClass
// имя начинается с большой буквы, затем опционально содержит буквы или дефисы
static final Pattern NAME = Pattern.compile("\\p{Lu}[-\\p{L}]*");

public static String mask(String txt) {
    if (null == txt || txt.isEmpty()) {
        return txt;
    }
    
    return NAME.matcher(txt).replaceAll(MyClass::mask);
}
```

Основная логика реализована в следующем методе:

- сначала проверяем наличие дефиса, здесь имеет смысл применить `String::replaceAll`:
  `return name.replaceAll("(\\p{L})(\\p{L}*)(-|$)", "$1***$3");`
- затем является ли имя длинным (более 7 символов), здесь можно воспользоваться как `replaceAll/replaceFirst`, так и "обычным" `substring`
- иначе найдено короткое имя, для которого достаточно к первому символу прибавить строку из звёздочек, полученную при помощи `String::repeat` (или какого-нибудь массива коротких строк).

```java
// class MyClass

private static String mask(MatchResult mr) {
    String name = mr.group();
    int n = name.length();
    
    if (name.contains("-")) {
        return name.replaceAll("(\\p{L})(\\p{L}*)(-|$)", "$1***$3");
    } else if (n > 7) {
        //name.charAt(0) + "***" + name.substring(n - 2);
        return name.replaceAll("(\\p{L})(.*{" + (n - 3) +"})(\\p{L}{2})", "$1***$3");
    }
    return name.charAt(0) + "*".repeat(n - 1);
}
```

Тест:

```
String str = "Екатерина Ян, Сергей Ак-Барсиков, коньяк Жан-Жак, Ро Дэ У, Рикки-Тикки-Тави";

System.out.println(str + "\n" + mask(str));
```

Вывод:

```
Екатерина Ян, Сергей Ак-Барсиков, коньяк Жан-Жак, Ро Дэ У, Рикки-Тикки-Тави
Е***на Я*, С***** А***-Б***, коньяк Ж***-Ж***, Р* Д* У, Р***-Т***-Т***
```